# Symfony setting a date field to single_text

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am following along with the symfony book and I got a form to display but whenever I change my code from:

```
->add('dueDate','date') to ->add('dueDate','date', array('widget' => 'single_text'))
```

I get this error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.

However, if I set it to text then it works fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `format` option as below and then check :

```
$builder->add('dueDate', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    // this is actually the default format for single_text
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
));
```

Comment: Turns it out it was a noob mistake of refreshing the website as opposed to reentering it.